# Get correct ctrl-tab order in Firefox without previews

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, tabs

For some reason Firefox has changed ctrl-tab to cycle through all tabs in left-to-right order, instead of last-used order. This is useless for those of us who have many tabs open.

Googling for a solution, the standard way of reverting this change seems to be to set `browser.ctrlTab.previews` to `true`. However, as the name implies, this also enables tab previews. This means that I get the correct order, but I'm only able to cycle through the 6 last used tabs, not all of them. This is, again, useles fo those of us who have many tabs open.

I want to ctrl-tab to cycle through all tabs in last-used order. I'd prefer to see a list of tab names while cycling, but other types of preview are acceptable.

Is this doable?